# How can i improve performance of a simple select query? (extremely slow)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I have an Entry table with 6.5 billion records, when I try to search for a certain number of records for a specific type, most of the time it's done relatively quickly, but in the case of the most frequent Entry type (60% of all) it takes a huge amount of time.
I also have a non clustered key Type_Deleted and my query looks like this:

```
 SELECT TOP (100000) [Id]
      ,[Name]
      ,[EntryType]
      ,[Deleted]
  FROM [dbo].[LifecycleEntry]
  WHERE EntryType = 1 AND IsDeleted = 0
```

In case EntryType 4 in will be less then second for TOP(100000) in case code 1 it will be 5min for TOP(1).

How can I find and fix the problem of it?

[image]

Comment: *"I also have a non clustered key Type_Deleted"* If that index is only on that column, it's unlikely to be "useful". An `INDEX` on `Deleted` *and* `EntryType`, which `INCLUDE`s `Name` would be much more useful (assuming `UniqueID` is a `CLUSTERED` `PRIMARY KEY`).

Comment: Also you appear to be missing an `ORDER BY` in your query.

Comment: @Larnu it is Deleted_EntryType. But how will ORDER BY help with performance?

Comment: Alternatively, you might find an index on `EntryType` which `INCLUDE`s `Name` and is filtered on `Deleted = 0` could be beneficial; this depends on if you often query for rows where `Deleted = 1` or not.

Comment: *"it is Deleted_EntryType"* so does it `INCLUDE` `name`? Can you include the DDL of your table and the (relevant) indexes in your post? [Pasting the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) will also help.

Comment: Maybe a filtered index could work for you?

Comment: No, does not include. I can't show anything from the commercial database. Thank you for advice, i will try, but i still do not understand why there is so big difference between different entrycode value in queries.

Comment: The query plan would be super useful - without it, we're just guessing.
I assume that entry_type and Deleted are columns with low cardinality - these usually do not benefit from having an index. 
An order_by, with a matching index, _might_ help (right now, the records selected in your limit are not guaranteed to be any particular selection).

Comment: "but in the case of the most frequent Entry type (60% of all) it takes a huge amount of time" It is natural. Most of the time it takes to transfer the records between server and caller.

Comment: You need to post `CREATE TABLE` including indexes and execution plan. Otherwise this question is pointless. No one else can answer it and the self answer you posted is of no interest to anyone (you solved it by hinting an index whose definition we can't see that exists on a table whose definition we can't see  that changed a bad execution plan that we cant see to a good execution plan that we cant see.

Answer (score 0):

I improved performance after forcing to use Non Clustered key, this key for some reason wasn't used for Type with Code 1, but in case other values always worked.

SELECT * FROM Entry WITH(INDEX (IX_EntryType_Deleted_Type))
WHERE Deleted = 0 AND EntryType = 1